# How to use WP hooks into ReactJS

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-rest-api

In my WordPress project i need to develop an application that has a  module about user profile. In WordPress there is a hook `is_user_logged_in()` to check if user is logged in or not. But now what is a flow to use this functionality into reactJS. As my profile data is rendering from header.jsx file.

```
if(user logged in){
 "then user profile will display"}
else{
 "user login screen will display"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by following the next steps:

1. **Backend.** Create API endpoint to check if the user logged. For example: /wp/api/user. In this action add php code that will checking by `is_user_logged_in()` and send response true or false.
2. **Frontend.** Create XMLHttpRequest by React ( for example I'm using **axios** library for this ) to URL that you created in the previous step. Finally, after getting a response you will know in your React app is a user logged.